# How do I enable "End Meeting Early" for all users in an organization in Exchange Admin Center?

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app

We want to adopt a company wide policy for all meeting to have a delayed 5 minutes start to all meetings. For example, meetings should start at 2:05 PM instead of 2:00 PM regardless of the user and time, it should always have a 5 minute delay at the hour or half an hour. Reading online on Microsoft forums I found out that this feature is not available as of yet, however we can apply "End Meeting Early" option using registry key and GPO.

End Meeting Early option is available individually for users in Outlook online. However, is there a way to activate this feature for all users in an organization?

Answer (score 0):

No, I have done some research, there is no way to enable this feature in exchange online eac, you should use group policy to realize this request.

For more details: [End appointments and meetings early](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_EnableEndEarly)

Comment: Any updates? If there is no issue, mark helpful reply as answer to close the thread. Your action would be helpful to other users who encounter the same issue and read this thread.

Comment: Yes, I have done research on my part as well. It is only available for users not organizations, as of yet. I saw some feature requests being made on Microsoft forums.

Comment: You could post your request in uservoice: https://office365.uservoice.com/

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it can be made the default either in the registry https://c7solutions.com/2019/04/save-time-have-all-your-meetings-end-early

Or admx/adml https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030

Comment: Please add more to this link-only answer so it can stand alone. Links rot all the time, and without the link this answer is useless.